# Swift : How do i make a master page structure in view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

I am working in a project that it contains a header view. There is a UIImageView inside header view. I want to derive this header view and its appearance (constraints,bg color etc.) on all of my other view controllers. So is that possible to do it just using Xcode designer ?

I created a view controller in storyboard and BaseViewController class. 
In second view controller, i created another class and derived it from BaseViewController. But this didn't work.

Comment: You cant inherit xib/storyboard. Thats a drawback of using Xib/Storyboard. What you can do though is create a independent view and add the view as subview in all other controllers

Answer (score 0):

Create the view in xib the use that view in all viewControllers in all storyboards. For creating a custom view you can see this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrgH522lbfA